# Help me out here. What is this guy asking?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

This guy seems like he has a fairly solid question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306676/php-insert-array-into-another-array

I swear I answered it but there is some language barrier. Can someone take a look and see if they can explain it to me?

Is *this* question appropriate for meta?

Comment: I think this user wants to *merge* two arrays, preserving the order of the target array. Questions that generate that number of comments generally have something wrong with either the question or the OP - you can only help so much before stepping back and walking away. Sometimes language and experience levels are a barrier.

Comment: That's a pretty worthy candidate for closing as Not a Real Question.

Comment: @Linuxios I probably would have if I had the rep, but since I didn't I took on the challenge of trying to figure out what he wanted. I won't make the mistake again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, if you can't figure out what the OP is saying (and it's not a problem on *your* side -- you feel that most folks won't be able to understand it), then you may flag ("does not belong on this site>NARQ") or vote to close as Not A Real Question. Be sure to leave a comment explaining what parts are confusing and asking the OP to fix that.